# How can I change a folder name in Visual Studio 2008 that contains a test project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I created a project that has unit tests in Visual Studio 2008 using the Unit Test Wizard.  It put that project inside a folder named "TestProject1".  Now I want to rename "TestProject1" to a more meaningful name. I can't see how do so from within Visual Studio.  Changing it outside of Visual Studio causes Visual Studio to ask me save the project upon a Build.  But then informs me that I can only save the project in "TestProject1."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rename the folder outside of Visual Studio.

Then open the .SLN file using a text editor like notepad and then change the reference to the folder to the new name.

Make sure the solution is not open in Visual Studio when this is being done.

Comment: Perfect!  I followed your instructions and was able to rename the folder.